# ASPNET Custom control add display:inline-block;

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom control that inherits `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`

When control is rendered add `style="display:inline-block;"`

I use  `Me.Style.Remove("display")` `Me.Style["display"]="something"` and other similar things but this code persist.

You can see same behavior in this simple control:

```
    public class HomeLink : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl {
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
        this.Attributes["style"] = "aaaa";
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        this.Attributes["style"] = "bbb";
    } }
```

And this code behind:

```
    <FC:HomeLink ID="HomeLink1" runat="server" width="100px" />
```

And render like this:

```
    <span id="HomeLink1" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;bbb"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a reflector you will see that each control inherits webcontrol rendered using tags "span" and "a" will have

```
Protected Overridable Sub AddAttributesToRender(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    ...
    If (Me.TagKey = HtmlTextWriterTag.Span OrElse Me.TagKey = HtmlTextWriterTag.A) Then
        Me.AddDisplayInlineBlockIfNeeded(writer)
    End If
    .....
End Sub

Friend Sub AddDisplayInlineBlockIfNeeded(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim isEmpty As Boolean = False
    If (Not Me.RequiresLegacyRendering OrElse Not MyBase.EnableLegacyRendering) Then
        If (Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.NotSet) Then
            Dim borderWidth As Unit = Me.BorderWidth
            If (borderWidth.IsEmpty) Then
                Dim height As Unit = Me.Height
                If (height.IsEmpty) Then
                    Dim width As Unit = Me.Width
                    isEmpty = width.IsEmpty
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If (Not isEmpty) Then
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "inline-block")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So to avoid applying style `display:inline-block` you have 2 options

1- add the following code to you web.config to enforce legacy rendering

```
<system.web>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
</system.web>
```

2- override method AddAttributesToRender and get width in variable and set control Width to empty value then excute base.AddAttributesToRender(writer) then add width if it was set

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Unit width = this.Width;
    this.Width = new Unit();

    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

    if (!width.IsEmpty)
        writer.AddStyleAttribute("width", width.ToString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Remove() method in the Style class, check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx) link.

Comment: What? My code, and NET documentation said that exists: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=ES-ES&k=k(SYSTEM.WEB.UI.CSSSTYLECOLLECTION.REMOVE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

use attributes it will work..

```
Me.Attributes["style"] = "display:inline-block;";
```

Comment: Don't work: I use this in PreRender...  `this.Attributes["style"]= "aaaaaa"'; base.OnPreRender(e); this.Attributes["style"] = "bbbbbbbbbb";` and have this result `style="display:inline-block;bbbbbbbbbb">`

Comment: you are in window application or web application..what is your code behind language..

Comment: I use: ASP.NET (.aspx)

Comment: that i made clear  from your tag..I am asking c# or vb.Net.And also is it possible for you to use jquery or javascript

Comment: I don't use jquery or any external library

Comment: instead of me replace your custom control name..if it din work then add a class to your custom control in code behind,using css style it

Answer (score 0):

A lack of a more elegant solution, you can override the render method:

```
      protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
      {
          //Create a new HtmlTextWriter to render the original control output
          var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
          System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
          System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter preWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(textWriter);
          base.Render(preWriter);

          //Here you can modify any output content
          sb.Replace("display:inline-block;", "");

          //Finally write control writer
          writer.Write(sb);
      }
```

I've tried with your code and it Works!
I hope help you,

Answer (score 0):

You could also ensure that Width and Height of you control is Empty (if it's possible), because span and anchor are inline control that has no Height or Width, that why a WebControl display is changed to inline-block so the height or width apply to the usercontrol.

If your control need a Height and Width, you could use as constructor and declare the tag has a DIV

```
public HomeLink ()
: base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
{
}
```